# A long list of glossary-items in two columns

Tags: tables, glossaries, linguistics

I have tried hard to look for a solution to my problems, but I can't manage to find it on this site or with Google. I have tried: `minipage`, `multicol`, `longtable`, `tabu`. I've read the documentation on `glossaries` and I can not make head or tails from it.

I've got a glossary, with linguistic gloss abbreviations in it. I just need the gloss entry abbreviation and the description. No need for a third part. To save paper, I would like the glossary to be in two columns (abbrev. descr. abbrev. descr.) and I want it not to be on a seperate page.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[openright,12pt,dutch]{report}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[nomain,nonumberlist,nogroupskip,nostyles]{glossaries} % voor de lijst met glossen. 
\usepackage{glossary-super}
\usepackage{leipzig} % voor glossen

\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{myglosses}{
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{
        \longtable{r l}
    }{
        \endlongtable
    }
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsclearpage}{} 

     % set how each entry should appear:
      \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{
        \glstarget{##1}{\textsc{\glossentryname{##1}}}
        &
        \glossentrydesc{##1} \\
    }
    \renewcommand*{\subglossentry}[3]{%
        \glossentry{##2}{##3}
    }
}

\begin{document}

What does \Pl{} mean? My (\Fsg{}.\Poss{}) houses (house-\Pl{}). \Agr, \Antip, \Ben, \Caus, \Compl, \Comp, \Third, \Dem, \Erg, \Fut, \F, \Loc, \Irr, \Impf, \Inf, \Ind, \Indf, \Ins, \Neg, \N, \M, \Nmlz, \Obj, \Obl, \Parg, \Prf, \Prs, \Prog. 

\printglossary[style=myglosses,type=\leipzigtype,title=]. 

\end{document}
```

Remember to run `makeglossaries`. I'd really appreciate your help with my thesis.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[openright,12pt,dutch]{report}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[nomain,nonumberlist,nogroupskip,nostyles]{glossaries} % voor de lijst met glossen. 
\usepackage{glossary-super}
\usepackage{leipzig} % voor glossen

\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{myglosses}{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
{\begin{multicols}{2}\raggedright}
{\end{multicols}}

    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsclearpage}{} 

     % set how each entry should appear:
      \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{
       \noindent\makebox[7em][l]{\glstarget{##1}{\textsc{\glossentryname{##1}}}}
        \glossentrydesc{##1}
    }
    \renewcommand*{\subglossentry}[3]{%
        \glossentry{##2}{##3}
    }
}


\renewcommand*{\glossarysection}[2][]{\section*{Glossary}}

%\setglossarystyle{inline}

\begin{document}

What does \Pl{} mean? My (\Fsg{}.\Poss{}) houses (house-\Pl{}). \Agr, \Antip, \Ben, \Caus, \Compl, \Comp, \Third, \Dem, \Erg, \Fut, \F, \Loc, \Irr, \Impf, \Inf, \Ind, \Indf, \Ins, \Neg, \N, \M, \Nmlz, \Obj, \Obl, \Parg, \Prf, \Prs, \Prog. 

\printglossary[style=myglosses,type=\leipzigtype,title=]. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way of using `multicol` with `\parbox` commands to format the glossary. The `section=section` package option is used to prevent a page break before the glossary by altering the sectioning level from the default chapter to section (which doesn't start a new page).

```
\documentclass[openright,12pt,dutch]{report}

\usepackage[nomain,nonumberlist,nogroupskip,nostyles,section=section]{glossaries} % voor de lijst met glossen.
\usepackage{leipzig} % voor glossen
\usepackage{multicol}
\makeglossaries


\newglossarystyle{myglosses}{%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{%
      \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
      \begin{multicols}{2}%
    }{%
      \end{multicols}%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsclearpage}{\columnbreak}%
     % set how each entry should appear:
      \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \parbox{.3\linewidth}{\hskip \fill\glstarget{##1}{\textsc{\glossentryname{##1}}}}%
        \hspace{.1\linewidth}%
        \parbox{.6\linewidth}{\glossentrydesc{##1}\hskip \fill}\par%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\subglossentry}[3]{%
        \glossentry{##2}{##3}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

What does \Pl{} mean? My (\Fsg{}.\Poss{}) houses (house-\Pl{}). \Agr, \Antip, \Ben, \Caus, \Compl, \Comp, \Third, \Dem, \Erg, \Fut, \F, \Loc, \Irr, \Impf, \Inf, \Ind, \Indf, \Ins, \Neg, \N, \M, \Nmlz, \Obj, \Obl, \Parg, \Prf, \Prs, \Prog.

\printglossary[style=myglosses,type=\leipzigtype,title=]

\end{document}
```

[image: two columns of glossary entries]

Answer (score 3):

I'll add an answer for leipzig 2.0 (which has just been added to CTAN, 2017-06-16). It's too late for your thesis, but might help someone else.

I have included a pre-defined multicolumn glossary style in this version of leipzig. After a lot of experimentation, I ultimately decided that any style based on a tabular format was no good, because they often do not break across pages nicely, and lists of gloss abbreviations are often multiple pages long.

Instead, the predefined block styles are built on the `alttree` and `mcolalttree` styles of the glossaries package. The easiest way to set the style for the glossary of abbreviations is to use the package option [mcolblock].

All unknown package options for leipzig are passed to glossaries. Therefore, like @cfr, I used the [section] option to print the glossary name in a section header instead of a chapter header. If you really want no title, you can uncomment one line to redefine the glossary section to do nothing.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[openright,12pt,dutch]{report}

% leipzig 2.0 has a simpler preamble declaration!
\usepackage[%
    mcolblock,% multicolumn block glossary
    section,% glossary begins with a section header (not chapter header)
]{leipzig} % voor glossen

\makeglossaries

% Uncomment if you want no chapter/section heading at all:
%\renewcommand*{\glossarysection}[2][]{}

\begin{document}

What does \Pl{} mean? My (\Fsg{}.\Poss{}) houses (house-\Pl{}). \Agr, \Antip, \Ben, \Caus, \Compl, \Comp, \Third, \Dem, \Erg, \Fut, \F, \Loc, \Irr, %\Impf, % changed to \Ipfv!
\Ipfv, \Inf, \Ind, \Indf, \Ins, \Neg, \N, \M, \Nmlz, \Obj, \Obl, \Parg, \Prf, \Prs, \Prog. 

\printglosses

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

You can also see that leipzig 2.0 fixes some errors! No more PL.pluralpl.

Comment: ```> No more PL.pluralpl``` Excellent! This kept coming back up when reinstalling LaTeX. I have spread the knowledge of the Leipzig package with my TeX linguistics friends and this really helps. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @RedmerKronemeijer! I am glad it is useful.

By the way, you can spread the news that anyone may contact me by email at any time. I'm much more likely to debug things if someone pings me on it.